# How to record sound 24/7

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording

I want to record sound from a particular microphone on a Windows 7 for an extended period of time.
The computer is on 24/7.
How can I achieve this?

**Background**
My neighbor is causing problems saying that I'm making noise even when I am not home. I thought of the idea of recording sound levels in my flat for factual evidence in-case this ever turns sour.

Comment: Is it the neighbor from the next house 30 yards away or the one from the next appartment behind the wall?

Comment: Behind the wall, to be honest she seems like one of these crazy lady with 5 cat types.

Comment: Can't you just add a mike to the PC in question and use recording software?

Comment: @Paul Yes, the main issue is how to archive all this data into a usable format.

Comment: PSA: In some states it is illegal to record conversations without consent of the parties involved.

Comment: @ioSamurai: I'm pretty sure in all states it is illegal for other people to have conversations in your home without your consent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**<sub>Short answer</sub>**
Create a scheduled task and use ffmpeg together with a batch file to record your microphone.

**<sub>Long answer</sub>**

1. Download [*ffmpeg-XXXX-win32-static.7z*](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) for Windows and extract it with 7-zip or Winrar
2. Copy `Bin\ffmpeg.exe` to a folder of your choice (You can delete the other files & folders)
3. Create a new text file and paste the following code.
   Save the file as *record.cmd* in the same folder as your *ffmpeg.exe*

   ```
   @echo off
   mkdir "My records"
   set outputpath=My records\record_%date:~-2,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.mp3
   ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="My microphone" -y -t 01:00:00 "%outputpath%"
   ```
4. Replace *My microphone* with your own microphone name.
   To get the name, open a CMD Window and head over to your ffmpeg.exe.
   This command lists all available devices: 
   `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`
   [image]
5. Create as scheduled task (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> » Taskschd.msc) and point it to your record.bat.
   Let it run each full hour so ffmpeg can split your audio in 1-hour files.

---

### The result after some hours

[image]

**Additional help**

- All used commands are explained at the [ffmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)
- It is possible to execute the whole process [in a hidden window](https://superuser.com/questions/546030/scheduling-silent-hourly-windows-defender-definition-updates-using-task-schedule/546062#546062) or in the background
- It is also possible to start and stop the [task per shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/57694/setting-a-shortcut-to-trigger-task-scheduler)
- Change the record time ("01:00:00") or output path ("My records\record") to your needs

Comment: This is a pretty slick solution, and should be easy to port to other systems that can run FFmpeg.

Comment: You can even use AWS CLI to upload recent recorded files to your S3 bucket. Thank your for your great answer, worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try out: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/ (Can save audio to file)

Otherwise I'd Google around for 'free audio recording software'.

Most audio recording software doesn't seem to be in the realm of surveillance management but you can certainly start a recording one day and come back the next, stop and start again etc.

Placement of the mic is also important since it's pickup probably isn't as good as your neighbors' ears.